# Who launched the request when visiting a website containing outer resources?

Tags: html

I am new to computer networks and have a simple question. Assuming that we want to visit a website www.aaa.com, and the website includes a picture . When we try to access aaa.com, who launched the resource request on bbb.com, the aaa.com server or the user-side browser? I have two thoughts:

- User first downloaded the html file of aaa.com and the browser executed the code in it, so the user browser finishes resource request.
- The aaa.com launches the request, and prepares all the sources, then gives back to user browser.
  Which idea is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a visitor is using a proxy which redirects all traffic through website `aaa.com` then what `bbb.com` site will see is a request made from the users browser.

Your HTML file essentially acts as a pointer to all the resources needed by the website; browser then fetches all the resources accordingly. This is usually called a `Cross-Origin` call.

[image]

You can open up your Developer Tools in your browser to see the calls under the `Network` tab.
If you want to delve deeper into the subject take a look at [CORS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).